# The apps playground

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

LinkedIn, Wikipedia, Facebook, Twitter, Stackoverflow, Wechat, Telegram, LaTeX, Overleaf, Snapchat, Netflix, WhatsApp, Formula 1, Pinterest, GitHub, YouTube, [...] are all playing checkers.

Instagram does not want to learn the rules while TikTok is strongly hesitating. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably horribly <s>wrong</s> right but...

> The checkers-playing apps have logos with at least two solid colors. The Tiktok logo technically has them, but gives the appearance of blur and wearing 3D glasses. The Instagram logo consists of white curves surrounded by a gradient.